# Removing every character from a string except digits

Tags: f#

I am currently trying to write a program, which is able to take a txt file and convert a table of numbers from that file into a list with numbers from column 1, another list from column 2 etc.

Due to the structure of the txt files, I have no problems making the lists from the numbers, the problem is how I should remove the irrelevant parts from the string created from the txt file.

My code as of now:

```
let mutable s = ""

let readerStream = System.IO.File.OpenText "x.txt"
let readFile (stream : System.IO.StreamReader) =
    while not(stream.EndOfStream) do
        let mutable line = stream.ReadLine ()
        s <- s + sprintf "%s" line.ToLower()
   stream.Close()

readFile readerStream
s <- s.[3600..1253900]
printfn "%s" s 
printf "%A" (String.length s)
```

My initial approach was to use String.Replace to remove every instance of any character other than a digit, but that quickly got messy and then I realized that the text above and below the columns also contained numbers, which would render that approach useless.

As mentioned above, the txt files all have a similar structure, which means I can remove most of the irrelevant text by indexing as seen on my third last line, and then I can use String.Replace to remove the remaining text, that I have no use for. This approach certainly works, but I was wondering if there was any smarter way of doing this.

I have attached one of those txt files, if it helps making the question easier to understand.

Before the column of numbers start and end, there is a keyword: "$$EOE" - now is there any way to make use of this fact?

Comment: `I have attached one of those txt files`, where is the attached text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to provide an answer without the text file, which I assume you will upload soon. I would make a stab at it, but the description and the code really don't match up right now.

What I can offer is that there are a few minor whitespace issues that are preventing it from compiling, and there are a couple of unnecessary `mutable` variables, and I think due to the sheer number of string concatenations you will want to use a `StringBuilder`. Here is an initial tidy up:

```
let sb = StringBuilder()

let readerStream = System.IO.File.OpenText "x.txt"
let readFile (stream : System.IO.StreamReader) =
    while not(stream.EndOfStream) do
        let line = stream.ReadLine ()
        line.ToLower() |> sb.Append |> ignore
    stream.Close()
readFile readerStream
let s = sb.ToString().[3600..1253900]
printf "%s" s 
printf "%i" (String.length s)
```

When you post the file contents, I will offer my thoughts on other approaches.

Comment: I will just accept this as an answer, but I figured it out myself after banging my head against the wall for a while.

Thanks a lot for taking your time, it's really nice of you :)